# TableLayoutPanel evenly spaced cells

Tags: c#, picturebox, spacing, tablelayoutpanel

I'm trying to get the columns in a TablePanelLayout to be evenly spaced.  It seems to work for some numbers, but not others.

2, 4, 5, 8, and 10 all work fine, but 3, 6, 7, and 9 do not.  The last cell always ends up slightly larger or smaller than the rest.

It seems like there's a limit in the float precision: 100 / 5 = 20 is nice and even.  But 100 / 6 = 16.66666... and it only shows 2 decimal places.

Anything that results in a repeating number when divided into 100 doesn't work.  I've tried using the Format > Horizontal/Vertical Spacing > Make Equal, which I saw in other threads, but it doesn't make a difference.

It's particularly noticeable since each cell contains a PictureBox with the SizeMode set to Zoom.  So one image is obviously not the same size as the rest.

Is there some other trick to ensure that they are absolutely even?  The whole form is resizeable, so it has to work at any reasonable scale.  Everything is set to Anchor on all 4 sides, the margins and padding are all 0.

I've run out of ideas...

Comment: Can you add additional columns and dynamically size those so that the number of columns with data divides out to an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind, I came up with a solution, though it feels a bit hackish.  In case anyone sees this, what I did was always make one more column/row than I actually need, and set the extra row to "AutoSize".  The other rows are then all rounded down, so instead of 16.67% or whatever, they're all actually 16.5%.  The extra auto-sized row then eats up the slack.  I don't like it, but it seems to work.

(I actually solved this a few hours after posting, but apparently I'm too much of a noob to be allowed to answer my own question without a waiting period.  Not sure I understand the point of that rule, you'd think that you'd want to encourage people to figure things out on their own, but whatever.)